# How to fix type error in telethon python scri

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I use telethone to forward message from telegram channel to my channel
code something like this:

```
 if message.media and isinstance(message.media, (MessageMediaPhoto, MessageMediaDocument)):
        return await client.send_message(destination_channel_id, message.text, file=message.media)
    if message.media and isinstance(message.media, (MessageMediaWebpage)):
        return None
    else: 
         return await client.send_message(destination_channel_id, message.text)
```

but if the peer message has an webpage pinned - i have

`TypeError: Cannot use <telethon.tl.types.MessageMediaWebPage object at 0x7f928ca75540> as file`

How should i fix it?

seeems like it try to send WebPage as file